# Encrypt QueryString from Classic ASP and Decrypt in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, asp.net-3.5

I want to encrypt QueryString in Classic ASP and decrypt in ASP.NET C#. I found several samples in either .NET or in Classic ASP, but I am not getting one with which I can encrypt in classic ASP and decrypt in .NET.

Any AES code in classic ASP as well as in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is finding en-de/cryption libs in the classic ASP domain, not in the .Net domain. However that challenge is becoming rather small if you are willing to mix in javascript on the server.

If you have a look at http://phrogz.net/tmp/serversidejsandvb.html you'll see that you can even mix vbscript and javascript in the server.

So google for encrypt lib javascript, plenty of libs around.